# How to make a ExternalSystemRunConfiguration of type Application, in IntelliJ plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

So, I've been looking around for this for awhile, and since Jetbrains doesn't really document Plugin development for their IDEs, I just haven't been able to find the answer. I just need to figure out what I should be using in the constructor of ExternalSystemRunConfiguration if I'm making a Application run configuration [Like this one](https://gyazo.com/985241b3d68d4d3e9e2725288362633b)

Comment: The [Run Configurations documentation](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/run_configurations.html) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

The "Application" run configuration is implemented by the [ApplicationConfiguration](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/execution/impl/src/com/intellij/execution/application/ApplicationConfiguration.java) class, not by `ExternalSystemRunConfiguration`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not exactly great with plugin development. and I wasn't aware of that

Comment: Also, if you'd be so kind, I need to find the way to set the value of "Use classpath of module" for the configuration.

Comment: Use the `setModule` method.

Comment: Thanks yole! Sorry for being such a noob